# Excel delete rows deleting wrong rows

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

This code is supposed to get all rows in the range that I specify, and delete ONLY the rows with no cell DATA in them. It's actually deleting every row in the range though. Why?

```
Range range = _sheet.get_Range("A25:A542", Type.Missing);
range = range.EntireRow;
range.Delete(Type.Missing);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can see your code did exactly what it supposed to do.

Comment: you're not specifying which cells within the row you want to delete. You're selecting the entire row with `range = range.EntireRow;` and `range.Delete(Type.Missing);` deletes that entire row

Comment: You should probably ask this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398770/how-to-clean-up-microsoft-office-interop-excel-workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type.Missing doesn't mean what you think it means. Type.Missing is a COM artefact - it just tells the Excel object that you're not providing that particular parameter. It's the kind of thing that's normally taken care of for you in VB.NET and VBA. C# 4.0 has support for optional parameters, which makes things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You do not check if any DATA exists, so the program deletes all rows from line 25 til line 542.

Comment: I thought Type.Missing check takes care of that in get_Range. How else would I do this?